# Notifications of flags

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flagging

I want to get notifications of stuff that I flagged. 
I would like to know:

- What question/answer it's about
- If it was declined or accepted

I want this notification on askubuntu.com
Possible workaround could be to get the  feature added in stackapplet, if @georgeEdison agrees.

Comment: If you flag a lot of posts I think this would be really annoying.

Comment: in the same way it's annoying of geting a lot of respons on questions / answers?

Comment: Not as much, no. Responses from other users usually invite me to act in some way, either by responding back or voting or accepting, etc. Flags usually require no action on my part, which is likely why SE doesn't include them in the inbox.

Comment: ok, but it's a notification I would like as an option..

Comment: The Ask Ubuntu API doesn't provide access to this information currently, so I'm afraid it won't show up in StackApplet until the API offers such access.

Comment: ok, then it's answered. sadly...

Answer (score 2):

You can see that information already in the flag weight report under the url

```
http://askubuntu.com/users/flag-weight/10698
```

or you can click on your flag weight in your profile to get there. It lists the posts you flagged and whether the flags were helpful or declined.

Comment: But I want it as an notification on the site. Like red notification all other notifications have.

Comment: What I mean is that i want that notification in mystackexchange inbox.

Comment: just pointing out that the link is dead, and now there isn't any concept of flag weight anymore